# `filetype plugin indent on` with `filetype=html` over-indents <script>

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

Since my last system update (I think), I have noticed this very annoying behavior.

```
# vim foo.html
# I go to insert mode, I type (no whitespace except newlines)

<html>
    <head>
                <script>
```

- That's four tabs in front of that `<script>`, instead of two.
- The two extra tabs are added right when I type that final closing `>`.
- With `set softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab` it's the same, but spaces.
- The other tags don't matter, the `<script>` can be anywhere like "`^\s+<script>`".
- It doesn't happen when `<script>` has *any* other attribute (like a `src`, `type` or `foo="bar"`)... could this be a bug?
- UPDATE: when I type a closing `</script>` *in the same line* the extra indentation is removed with, again, the final `>`.

```
# .vimrc
filetype plugin indent on

# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 17 2020 21:54:53)
Included patches: 1-1704
Compiled by Arch Linux
…
```

Comment: Probably bug in indent plugin of html.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm inclined to agree with @MaximKim based on the very minimal vimrc you show. I get 3*2 spaces with my config, but `<esc>==` actually fixes it? the JS indenting inside `<script>` is generally not too great

Comment: Looks like [7ff78465f](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/7ff78465f#diff-4fbf4cd2ef9bb7a186b50c1817c90033ef0d2e198378152ece90d04dc87bf2e6R589) broke it; if I revert that then `<script>` will actually be on the same indent as `<head>`, which isn't really correct either. I don't really know what a fix is, but you can put a copy of `indent/html.vim` in `~/.vim/indent/html.vim` without this change to get the old behaviour back.

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij et al, I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7215)